# App with conditional telephony permissions won't download to tablets

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

My app conditionally supports telephony - e.g. make a phone call, send a text - but it is being blocked by the Android Store to download to my Nexus 7 (and presumably other non telephony devices).

I have searched forums extensively and, according to some people, I should put "required=false" in my manifest permissions.  That, apparently, is insufficient.

Here's what I have in the manifest, regarding permissions:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" /> <!-- needed for 4.0 only -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have also tried uses-permission instead of uses-feature.  No difference.

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

> These permissions: CALL_PHONE, CALL_PRIVILEGED, MODIFY_PHONE_STATE,
>   PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, READ_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, RECEIVE_MMS,
>   RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH, SEND_SMS, WRITE_APN_SETTINGS, WRITE_SMS
>   implies **android.hardware.telephony** feature requirement.
>
> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for finding that buried info.  Do you know if I should change my "features" back to "permissions" and remove the "required=false", except for "android.hardware.telephony"?  Or, alternative, should I remove them altogether?  If you know, that would shorten my experimentation cycles.

Comment: You should revert back everything to `uses-permission`, then remove all the `android:required="false"`, and then add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />`.

Comment: Ok, will try.  I just ran the suggested aapt tool and it doesn't report any problems with the broken version, regarding telephony :(

Comment: Just verified.  It now installs on nexus 7!

Comment: I'll award the bounty, but SO is making me wait 16 hours.